# iOS Facebook SDK - Force user to enter credentials

Tags: ios, facebook

Working on an iOS app where there's a central user and many guest users.  I want the guest  users to be able to log in to their Facebook account on the app without having to log out the central user. I've tried setting up a new FBSession with the FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView and setting up my own token caching strategy (where the token actually isn't cached at all), but it still uses the default app user's credentials and doesn't show the login web view window.

According to the FB iOS sdk documentation, setting the behavior to FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView is supposed to force a web view to show where the user has to enter their credentials, yet in my app it just auto authorizes the currently logged in central user.

I copied over much of this code from the Switch Users sample that FB provides, only I took out the 'slots' as it put an upper limit on the number of guest users. Is this part of the problem?

```
FBSessionLoginBehavior behavior = FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView;
FacebookCustomerTokenCachingStrategy *tokenCachingStrategy = [[FacebookCustomerTokenCachingStrategy alloc] init];
self.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil
                                    permissions:nil
                                urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                             tokenCacheStrategy:tokenCachingStrategy];

[self.session openWithBehavior:behavior
             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                 FBSessionState status,
                                 NSError *error) {                     
                 //do whatever                   
             }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Basically, calling the following:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Only clears the local FB session information but not the Safari cookies.  So, after I log in the user, I clear the Safari cookies:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

It isn't very elegant, but it works. Now, when the next user tries to log in, it forces them to enter their credentials.

Comment: I'm seeing some odd things with this approach. I'm using Parse, which delegates to the Facebook SDK for logging in users via Facebook. However, I never see any cookies with Facebook domains. This worked great for Twitter auth, but I can't seem to get the active session to actually close and clear the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try clicking the account settings of your registered facebook account then click apps and remove the application authorized?

Edit

I know of some apps that does this too but personally im not sure of how to do it. In my opinion i think the app needs to force the facebook session to auto loggout of the app. Cuz there is a method to detect whether the user facebook account is logged in so i think there should be a method to do the opposite too, sorry

Comment: Yes. It does bring the login window up, but only to show what the app is asking for. After that, it just does an auto login and I'm left with the same issue.